# Помогите правильно написать код

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo')
yt.title
yt.thumbnail_url
yt = YouTube(
    'http://youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo',
    on_progress_callback=progress_func,
    on_complete_callback=complete_func,
    proxies=my_proxies,
    use_oauth=False,
    allow_oauth_cache=True
    )



yt.streams.filter(progressive=True)[
<Stream: itag="18" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.42001E" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">,
<Stream: itag="22" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.64001F" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">]



stream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(22)
stream.download()load()
```

если запустить, то вылетет ошибка:

```
  File "C:\Python code\first_project.py", line 17
    <Stream: itag="18" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.42001E" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">,
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 210ms]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Опиши свой код подробнее
Что ты уже сделал? Что нужно сделать? В чем именно у тебя заключается трудность и что не работает.

Comment: Добавьте минимальный пример кода, добавьте метку библиотеки. По-моему, вы используете pytube

Comment: Какой-то кусок данных и всё. В чём суть вопроса? )

Comment: У вас перемешан код с выводом кода. Уберите `<Stream:...`, сделайте просто `print(*yt.streams.filter(progressive=True), sep='\n')` и оно выведет само эти самые `<Stream:..`

Comment: CrazyElf а можеш полный код скинуть а то мне не понятно

Comment: Переоткроют - кину код в ответе, а так неудобно. Там и в последней строке кода тоже какая-то ботва

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, вот так код работает и что-то скачивает:

```
# !pip install pytube
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo')
yt.title
yt.thumbnail_url
yt = YouTube(
    'http://youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo',
    #on_progress_callback=progress_func,
    #on_complete_callback=complete_func,
    #proxies=my_proxies,
    use_oauth=False,
    allow_oauth_cache=True
    )

print(*yt.streams.filter(progressive=True), sep='\n')

#[
#'<Stream: itag="18" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.42001E" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">',
#'<Stream: itag="22" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.64001F" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">'
#]

stream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(22)
stream.download()
```

Вывод:

```
<Stream: itag="17" mime_type="video/3gpp" res="144p" fps="12fps" vcodec="mp4v.20.3" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
<Stream: itag="18" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="24fps" vcodec="avc1.42001E" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
<Stream: itag="22" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="24fps" vcodec="avc1.64001F" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
/content/YouTube Rewind 2019 For the Record  YouTubeRewind.mp4
```

Скачанный файл:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 87993287 Dec  2 14:31 'YouTube Rewind 2019 For the Record  YouTubeRewind.mp4'
```

У вас вывод был перемешан с кодом, ну и другие проблемы были. Я закомментировал лишнее.

Comment: спасибо тебе CrazyElf что помог мне :)